# How do I call a graphical class in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, draw

I've been coding a simulation for a traffic flow network in Java, and the class that is supposed to graphically model the network looks as follows:

```
public class Map extends JPanel {
BufferedImage truck1;

public Map() throws IOException{
    truck1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Truck.png"));
}

protected void paintcomponent (Graphics g) {
super.paintComponent(g);

g.drawImage(truck1, 50, 100, 300, 300, this);
}
}
```

In my main() function, I instance the object as follows at the very beginning of the function:

```
Frame F1 = new Frame();
F1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
F1.setSize(500,500);
F1.setVisible(true);
Map map = new Map();
map.setOpaque(true);
F1.add(map);
F1.setVisible(true);
```

However, when I run the program, the only output is a blank window with a slightly darker grey small square exactly in the middle at the top of the window. I've added Truck.png to the project, and I can't see any reason why it shouldn't display properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does the import look like for class Map? Make sure that you using your Map class and not any other implementtion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Components should be added to the frame before the frame is made visible.
2. You are using a FlowLayout for your frame. A FlowLayout respects the preferred size of all components. Your Map class doesn't have a preferred size so the size defaults to (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint. Override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the Map class to return the appropriate size for the component.

Comment: Thanks; it seems that it does change. However, now the darker grey area (which I assume is the panel area) is just much larger (according to the dimensions I gave it with map.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500)); ) but there is still no output of the image declared in the map class. Any ideas?

Comment: 1) The image should be drawn at location (0, 0). 2) the preferred size should be the size of the image, not a random value. 3) You should be using a `JFrame` not a Frame. Don't know if any of these make a difference. If not, then you need to make sure the image is being read. Also, why are you even doing custom painting, you can just display an Icon on a JLabel and add the label to the frame.